# string urlsession response is not handled correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I am beginner in swift , I created post URLSession and I wanted to get the string response from it and if I get  "EXIST" that's mean the user exists and I show the alert , and if I get "OK" the opposite is true.
what I am trying to do is handle that response in that way , I see in playground
the response like this "EXIST"  or "OK" but when I want to compare it do not work and none of my alerts are executed

//here my function

```
 @IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {

        
        print("hello")
          if(txtPassword.text != txtPasswordrepeat.text) {
              
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register Failed", message: "Passwords Mismatch", preferredStyle: .alert)
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
              self.present(alert, animated: true)
            print("passwords mismatch")
              
          }else {
          
          //post
      
          guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/register/") else {
          return
          }
          
          let bodyparameters = ["name": txtName.text,"lastname": txtLastname.text, "phone": txtPhone.text,"email": txtEmail.text, "password": txtPassword.text]
         
          var request = URLRequest(url: url)
          request.httpMethod = "POST"
          request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
          guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyparameters, options: []) else{
              return
              }
          request.httpBody = httpBody
          let session = URLSession.shared
          session.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
              if let response = response {
                  print(response)
              }
              
            if let data = data , let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                 
                      print(data)
                      
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          
                          
                        let string = dataString as! String
                        print(string)
                        if(string.elementsEqual("EXIST") == true  ){
                             
                              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register Failed", message: "User Already Exist", preferredStyle: .alert)
                              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                              self.present(alert, animated: true)
                            
                              
                          }else if(string.elementsEqual("OK") == true){
                          
                              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Register Successful", message: "User Registred", preferredStyle: .alert)
                              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                              self.present(alert, animated: true)
                              
                          }
                      
                      }
                                   
              }
              
          }.resume()
          
          }
        
    }
```

//play ground response

```
 2020-12-12 14:06:55.285299-0800 Bicycall[25347:386347] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000036f0140> { URL: http://localhost:3000/login } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
        Connection =     (
            "keep-alive"
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            74
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:06:55 GMT"
        );
        Etag =     (
            "W/\"4a-yeGoMwACtIYJqSJyS6bmKwCePsk\""
        );
        "Keep-Alive" =     (
            "timeout=5"
        );
        "X-Powered-By" =     (
            Express
        );
    } }
    74 bytes
    21
    
    INSERT SUCCESSFULLY
    21
    hello
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000036fa6c0> { URL: http://localhost:3000/register/ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
        Connection =     (
            "keep-alive"
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            7
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:07:04 GMT"
        );
        Etag =     (
            "W/\"7-cf+VCoacHzeb2ZclL0nsiKzxBq4\""
        );
        "Keep-Alive" =     (
            "timeout=5"
        );
        "X-Powered-By" =     (
            Express
        );
    } }
    7 bytes
    "EXIST"
    hello
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000036e7bc0> { URL: http://localhost:3000/register/ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
        Connection =     (
            "keep-alive"
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            7
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:07:06 GMT"
        );
        Etag =     (
            "W/\"7-cf+VCoacHzeb2ZclL0nsiKzxBq4\""
        );
        "Keep-Alive" =     (
            "timeout=5"
        );
        "X-Powered-By" =     (
            Express
        );
    } }
    7 bytes
    "EXIST"
    hello
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000036ebcc0> { URL: http://localhost:3000/register/ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
        Connection =     (
            "keep-alive"
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            7
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Sat, 12 Dec 2020 22:07:07 GMT"
        );
        Etag =     (
            "W/\"7-cf+VCoacHzeb2ZclL0nsiKzxBq4\""
        );
        "Keep-Alive" =     (
            "timeout=5"
        );
        "X-Powered-By" =     (
            Express
        );
    } }
    7 bytes
    "EXIST"
```

I am wondering about what I am missing here

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127152/how-do-i-get-a-popup-dialog-box-in-swift-playgrounds) help?

Comment: the problem is not in alert , the problem is that this :   if(string.elementsEqual("EXIST") == true  )      is not executed and also this else if(string.elementsEqual("OK") == true)

Comment: `string.elementsEqual("EXIST") == true ` ? vs `string == "EXIST"` ? Same for the "OK" test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO and Swift!

Your server is sending `"EXIST"`, but you are checking for `EXIST`.

IOW, instead of `string.elementsEqual("EXIST") == true`, try `string.elementsEqual("\"EXIST\"") == true`.

But don't stop there. Simplify the expression to `string == "\"EXIST\""`.